# Change input button's onClick parameter using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

I'm making an Android Web Application, and I'm using JQuery Mobile. My question is:

Is it possible to change the `onClick` event's parameter using Javascript?
I will be using Ajax post request to get the primary key attribute of my row from the database. And after getting the primary key, I want to set the parameter of the input button's `onClick` event.

Here's the structure of my program:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"url.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{input:input},
    success: function (result)
    {
        //Set my input button's onclick
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want to assign a click event handler within `success`?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible. The `result` is the primary key variable that I'm referring.

Comment: But what do you mean by setting the parameter? What's your input's id? For example, if `result` is `abc`, you want to assign a click handler to an `input` whose `id` is `abc`?

Comment: I would just assign the new pk to the input element via a data attribute, then you can pull this out in your handler - that way you dont have to keep rebinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function (result)
{
  $("#" + result).click(function () {
    // do something
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
yourelement.addEventListener('click', yourfunction);
```

or this

```
yourelement.addEventListener('click', function() {
   //your code here
});
```

or in jquery

```
$('yourelement').click(yourfunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this instead:

```
$('#element').click({id: id}, handleClick);
```

If, for example, the click handler is somewhere outside the scope:

```
function clickHandler(ev) {

    var id = ev.data.id;
    // use id

}
```